# How to solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+a_n} $ when sequence {a_n} is defineds as..

Tags: sequences-and-series

If sequence ${a_n}$ is defined as $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)$

what is the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+a_n} $?

Comment: $a_i + 1 = s_{i-1}$ where $s_i$ is the [Sylvestoer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_sequence). The series sum to $1$, it is a will known? infinite [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) representation of $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the first few terms of the sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ and the first few partial sums of the series $\sum\frac1{1+a_n}$. You'll discover the pattern
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+a_k} = 1-\frac1{a_{n+1}},
$$
which you can prove by induction with the aid of @Simpson17866's hint. Finally use the fact that $a_n\to\infty$, which you can also prove using the same hint. (Prove there exists $k>1$ such that
$$a_n\ge k^{2^n}$$
for all $n\ge2$.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $a_{n+1}=a_n*(a_n+1)$

Does this help?

Comment: Sorry, but can I have more hint? I don't know what to use to solve the series.  Do I have to use the equation 1/1+a_n = a_n/a_(n+1)? or is there a way to find out what {a_n} is?

Comment: I'm actually not sure either. Microsoft Excel says that the first few terms add up to pretty close to 1, and you can approximate $a_{n+1} ≈ (a_n)^2$ for large enough values of n, in which case $(a_n) ≈ k^{2^n}$, but I'm still not sure how to turn that sum into a simpler formula. Might I ask where you first found this sequence?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure of the source. I found it in a worksheet I was solving.